# Multiple Threads: Replication On Couchbase Lite In Android

Tags: android, multithreading, couchbase-lite

When I run replication on Couchbase Lite in Android from UI Thread, it happens that the replication executes in another thread and notifications (Via addChangeListener() method) are received in a third Thread. My code for Pull Replication is as follow:

```
Replication pullRep = getDatabase().createPullReplication(syncUrl);
pullRep.setContinuous(true);
pullRep.addChangeListener(this);
pullRep.start();
```

My question is: How can I run synchronous replication or at least get notifications on the same Thread from which replication was started ?

My opinion is that replication must occur in the current thread. The developer must handle thread issues.

I´m very new with Couchbase Lite and maybe I´m wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if I'm misunderstanding your situation, but I believe what you're trying to say is you can't update the UI with changes discovered in the Couchbase listener because the listener operates on a background thread and not the UI thread.  Am I correct?

You definitely don't want to run potentially long tasks on the UI thread because it will create a poor UX.  Asynchronous is the way to go.

You might try something like this instead:

```
Handler threadHandler = new Handler();

couchbaseDatabase.addChangeListener(new Database.ChangeListener() {
    public void changed(Database.ChangeEvent event) {
        // Alter variables related to the UI (maybe an array for a list view)
        threadHandler.post(updateUI);
    }
});

final Runnable updateUI = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Refresh the UI
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

Of course what I pasted is just bits and pieces and not a true working example.  My point here is that I used a `Handler`.  There are a ton of other ways that will work as well.

Would this work for you?

Best,

Comment: Can I call couchdatabase.createPullReplication(syncUrl); in Intent service for make, responsive UI.